# Bazel target not declared in package

Tags: bazel

My directory structure is as follows:

```
main
| WORKSPACE
| external
> | BUILD
```

I have a single BUILD file under `external`. My workspace file pulls the AWS SDK:

```
load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:repositories.bzl", "rules_foreign_cc_dependencies")
rules_foreign_cc_dependencies()

_ALL_CONTENT = """\
filegroup(
    name = "all_srcs",
    srcs = glob(["**"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
"""

new_git_repository(
    name = "aws_sdk",
    remote = "https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp",
    branch = "master",
    build_file_content = _ALL_CONTENT,
    init_submodules = True,
    recursive_init_submodules = True,
)
```

and my BUILD file builds it:

```
load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:defs.bzl", "cmake")

cmake(
    name = "aws",
    cache_entries = {
        "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release",
        "BUILD_ONLY": "dynamodb",
        "BUILD_SHARED_LIBS": "ON", 
        "ENABLE_TESTING": "OFF",
    },
    lib_source = "@aws_sdk//:all_srcs",
    out_shared_libs = [
        "libaws-cpp-sdk-core.so",
        "libaws-cpp-sdk-dynamodb.so",
    ]
)
```

However, when I try and run `bazel build //external:aws --verbose_failures`, I get this error:

```
ERROR: Skipping '//external:aws': no such target '//external:aws': target 'aws' not declared in package 'external' defined by /path/to/WORKSPACE
WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.
```

I'm really not sure why this error is coming up. Is there something I'm missing?

EDIT: I found that it is because I changed the BUILD directory from `library` to `external`. It seems to build when I change it back to `library`; is there a way I can get it to build using a new directory name?

Answer (score 1):

`external` is one of the special package names. Pick pretty much any other name instead.

I think using `//external` deprecated, but it's still handled specially for backwards compatibility. The docs don't really talk about it.

I think [Label.ABSOLUTE_PACKAGE_NAMES](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/4fd6a8443a75992ca57b5116dc5ddc9d43bd97b2/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/cmdline/Label.java#L62) in the Bazel source is the full list of package names which are special like this. It's currently `conditions`, `visibility`, and `external`, and is unlikely to change because any change can break backwards compatibility in ways that are hard to fix. Those have all been around for a long time, nowadays Bazel has better ways to introduce new identifiers in ways that can't conflict with user code like this.

Answer (score 0):

Brian is correct that `//external` is a special package name, but if you *really need* to store the directories under `external`, there's experimental support that re-arranges Bazel's internal implementation to allow subpackages in `//external`.

First, move `external/BUILD` to `external/aws/BUILD`. It wouldn't work with `external/BUILD`.

Then, use these flags:

```
$ bazel build //external/aws:aws --experimental_sibling_repository_layout --experimental_disable_external_package
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
Analyzing: target //external/aws:aws (41 packages loaded, 199 targets configured)
    Fetching @local_config_cc; Running xcode-locator
    Fetching @aws_sdk; Cloning origin/master of https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp
    Fetching @cmake-3.22.2-macos-universal; fetching
    Fetching ...versal; Extracting /private/var/tmp/_bazel_jingwen/91b505447ea4b3a0df1e091fb8e7029a/external/cmake-3.22.2-macos-univ\
ersal/temp12961087259543774657/cmake-3.22.2-macos-universal.tar.gz
```